# Quero gerar uma tabela de R para Latex

Tags: ggplot2, latex, r

Quero gerar uma tabela com os dados do summary do R com os resultados que obtive, sei que tem uma biblioteca chamada stargazer que faz, mas não encontrei a documentação.

Comment: `stargazer` é um pacote CRAN e tem uma [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/vignettes/stargazer.pdf).

Comment: Obrigado Rui Barradas.

Answer (score 2):

```
> require("xtable")
Carregando pacotes exigidos: xtable
> data("iris")
> xtable(summary(iris))
% latex table generated in R 3.4.1 by xtable 1.8-2 package
% Wed Sep 20 15:24:36 2017
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlllll}
\hline
&  Sepal.Length &  Sepal.Width &  Petal.Length &  Petal.Width &       Species \\ 
 \hline
1 & Min.   :4.300   & Min.   :2.000   & Min.   :1.000   & Min.   :0.100   & setosa    :50   \\ 
2 & 1st Qu.:5.100   & 1st Qu.:2.800   & 1st Qu.:1.600   & 1st Qu.:0.300   & versicolor:50   \\ 
3 & Median :5.800   & Median :3.000   & Median :4.350   & Median :1.300   & virginica :50   \\ 
4 & Mean   :5.843   & Mean   :3.057   & Mean   :3.758   & Mean   :1.199   &  \\ 
5 & 3rd Qu.:6.400   & 3rd Qu.:3.300   & 3rd Qu.:5.100   & 3rd Qu.:1.800   &  \\ 
6 & Max.   :7.900   & Max.   :4.400   & Max.   :6.900   & Max.   :2.500   &  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Se eu entendi bem o que você quer, uma possibilidade é usar o pacote "xtable" retorna um objeto do R no formato de tabela do latex.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução utilizando o pacote `stargazer` é:

```
install.packages("stargazer")
library(stargazer)

data("iris")
stargazer(do.call(cbind, lapply(iris,summary)), type = "latex")
```